# Decrypting Drupal encryption with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, encryption, drupal

I've been asked to investigate decryption by query from a MySQL database.
Drupal 7 is used for for webpages that store and display webform data in a MySQL v. 5.5 database. 
Mcrypt AES CBC Mode is used for encrypting selected table columns. 
I have been given the private key in clear text.
A v.8 MySQL database has been created to hold decrypted data.
A data import of various tables would be done from the v.5.5 database to the v8 one, followed by the decryption of a number of columns in table webform_submitted_data.
Between having the private key and MySQL v8 having the additional abilities of block_encryption_mode and an initialization vector for AES_DECRYPT, it was thought decryption could be done with a database query.

A typical encrypted column has this sort of content:
a:6:{s:4:"text";s:128:"AVcdpc+pHcU4/LjBkG+LllYxGEVVdBRD0+fThxkGD7q9zUFXx+H2lcYOWK05Y5483MOGaJuM6yMNIYjcCpyx6s0JyU7d2wJMWH+jLvOSoezaVPNmGKB9/cykAnCBTiC5";s:6:"method";s:14:"mcrypt_aes_cbc";s:12:"key_provider";s:15:"drupal_variable";s:7:"options";a:1:{s:6:"base64";b:1;}s:15:"method_settings";s:0:"";s:17:"provider_settings";a:1:{s:6:"method";s:17:"variable_contents";}}

Many variations of the following sort of approach have been used but with success:

```
SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
SET @key_str = SHA2('My private key',512);
SET @init_vector = RANDOM_BYTES(16);
SET @crypt_str = AES_ENCRYPT('text',@key_str,@init_vector);
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(@crypt_str,@key_str,@init_vector);
```

Given the circumstances is it possible to decrypt the data via MySQL query?
Is there some missing piece that would make it work?

Comment: That's not the actual ciphertext. That's the encoded ciphertext plus some metadata, all run through PHP's serialize function. Even if you can come up with some convoluted SQL query that would decrypt this successfully, why bother? Write a PHP script to do it and call it a day.

Comment: Thanks for the information and the idea. The end goal is to have an automated process that decrypts the data and writes it to the v.8 MySQL database. My access is limited to the two MySQL databases and does not include Drupal or the webserver. The hope is to accomplish decryption without further access or tasks for our web/Drupal specialists.

Comment: You don't need Drupal, only PDO and the unserialize function. And then you can decrypt using either the openssl extension or AES_DECRYPT in the database (mcrypt is abondoned for quite a while now; don't use it anymore). Having the Drupal code would be handy to look at what it does, exactly (like where is the IV stored), but you don't need it at runtime.

Comment: Thanks again Peter. I will start looking into this and let you know what happens.